# Polite expression for saying something in short

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for an expression that is used when you have a lot to tell about a specific matter but you will say only a short summary, usually due to courteousness towards the conversation partner, e.g. I am writing someone an email stating something. I have sent him multiple emails before regarding the same subject. So the email will go something like this:

> I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails. I will _______ with saying ...

I also believe the general form for the expression is *"I will _______ with saying ..."*, where *______* means something like *being content with*.

Comment: _summarize by saying_ works.  So does _content myself with saying_, if you must have "with."  Or you can say "To summarize" or "In summary"

Comment: *content myself with saying* sounds pretty good. It might just be what I had on my mind, but I'm not sure yet. I don't necessarily have to have "with", anything along that line works, e.g: to say, by saying, ...

Comment: "cut to the chase", or "get on with it"...

Comment: @Xanne, post that as an answer. I remembered; it was actually what I had in mind (its outlines at least).

Comment: Using @Xanne 's “content myself with” would indeed seem to be the best way to go, but there seems to be a missing “therefore” (or maybe something, like an "Although + nevertheless") to connect the ideas contained in your two sentences. …….  

“[Although] Without/Not wanting to [fatigue/trouble you by] repeat[ing] here **all of** the points discussed in my previous emails, I will [nevertheless] **therefore** content myself with summarizing them as follows: ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write **"I will summarize by saying"** or **"I will content myself with saying"**

Alternatively, you can say **"To summarize"** or **"In summary"**, preceding any of these with "Therefore" if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the word **suffice** seems appropriate.

> to be enough or adequate for; satisfy.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suffice?s=t

So you could say:

> I will suffice with saying ...

Comment: I'm not relly sure whether "**I** will suffice" has the correct meaning. This technically means "I am enough" but what I want to say is "what I'm about to say is enough". There is actually the common expression *suffice it to say that...* which works here, but I'm looking for something with the form I stated in my question.

Comment: @user2268997 you make a valid point about "**I** will suffice."  You could alternatively say "**It** will suffice to say" which is a little less idiomatic than *suffice it to say*.

Answer (score 2):

"I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails. I will ***[confine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confine)*** myself to..."

> Keep or restrict someone or something within certain limits of (space, scope, or time)

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confine

Answer (score 0):

How about:

For the sake of brevity, I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the part that comes after this, i.e: "but I will say this ..."

Answer (score 0):

1. *I'll [briefly mention](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/briefly)…*
2. *To [recap](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recap),*… ,
3. *I will just [mention in passing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-passing)…*
4. *I will [limit myself by saying](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22limit+myself+by+saying%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPjsTfs8PVAhWDtBQKHYv7D-AQ_AUICSgA&biw=1440&bih=678&dpr=1)…*

Sources: Oxford Dictionaries, Collins Dictionary, and Google.

Answer (score 0):

I will **spare you the details**... (or *spare you with the details*)

The idiom here is **spare me**, and it is covered in this ELU question ([I thought “spare me with …” means “don't bother me with the details of …”. Does it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189/i-thought-spare-me-with-means-dont-bother-me-with-the-details-of-d))

So your statement might be

> I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails. I will **spare you the details** by saying ...

From [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/spare-someone-the-details)

> to not tell someone every detail about something because it is too boring, personal, or unpleasant

Another common expression is **save (us) some time by**. It's literal meaning is clear, but its subtext is that there is much that will be omitted. It might be understood that the missing information has already been covered or, for some other reason, it is not completely necessary to make a point.

Your statement would become something like this:

> I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails. I will **save some time** by saying ...

or

> **To save (some) time**, I will not repeat here the points I stated in my previous emails...

Similar alternatives, that have a polite tone, include **in the interest of saving (us both some) time** or the idiom **[for the sake of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+sake+of) brevity**.